# Unwanted termination of Program

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am using a scanf function. The number I am asking the user to input is a long integer named myNumber. However, when I put in the value, the program gives "segmentation fault: 11"

```
long double ObtainNumber (myNumber)
{

    scanf("%lf", &myNumber);
    while (myNumber > 999999999)
        {
            printf("Error. Please enter a number with no greater than 9 digits\n");
            scanf("%lf", &myNumber);
        }

    return (myNumber);
}
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong?

Comment: We need to know the type of myNumber, and also the rest of the code, atleast that which runs right after this patch.

Comment: How is myNumber defined?

Answer (score 2):

```
long double ObtainNumber (/* you have no type name here */myNumber)
```

Unless you specify a type of `myNumber`, its type is assumed to be `int`. When you pass a pointer to `int` to `scanf` for the `%lf` specifier, you get undefined behavior.

You need to specify the type of `myNumber` to be `double`

```
long double ObtainNumber (double myNumber)
```

Note that this is not going to let you pass the value of `myNumber` back to the caller: the value will be set in a parameter which is passed by value; it will be discarded as soon as the function exits.

If you need to return the value from the function, you need to pass a pointer to `myNumber`:

```
long double ObtainNumber (double *myNumberPtr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare the type of the `myNumber` argument to your function, so it's assumed to be an `int`. You then go on to pass it to a `scanf` which expects it to be a `double`, and all kinds of bad things end up happening.

In this case, it's not clear why `myNumber` is an argument at all -- it certainly doesn't affect what the function does at all. You probably mean to just declare it as a local variable:

```
long double ObtainNumber(void)
{
    long double myNumber;
    scanf("%lf", &myNumber);
    ...
```

By the by, `long double` is unlikely to be the type you actually want. It's a kind of funky extended-precision type which can vary in size based on the architecture, compiler, and system you're working with. ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)) It's rarely used, nor necessary. `double` is easier to type, and more likely to behave the way you expect.