# scanf Terminating Program

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that converts a base n number to base 10. I have 4 functions not including main: ObtainNumber, GetBase, ConvertNumberToBase10, GetMyExponential. My main function executes the functions in the following order: GetBase, ObtainNumber, GetMyExponential, ConvertNumberToBase10. My program runs both the GetBase function and the ObtainNumber function. However, I use a scanf function in my ObtainNumber function and the program does not continue on to the other functions:

```
    long int ObtainNumber (long int myNumber)
    {

        scanf("%ld", &myNumber);
        while (myNumber > 999999999)
            {
                printf("Error. Please enter a number with no greater than 9 digits\n");
                scanf("%ld", &myNumber);
            }

        return (myNumber);

}
```

I was wondering why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the program does not continue to other function? You do know that at the invocation of scanf() it awaits for user input through the stdin, right?

If that's not it then we would need a bit more details and/or code to be able to assist you.

Comment: Have you considered eating the newline that is sitting in your input buffer after the first failure? `" %ld"`, for example? The fact that you're not checking the return result of `scanf()` is a problem in itself. Its probably returning 0 indicating no value was parsed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwanted termination of Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554718/unwanted-termination-of-program)

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf()` function returns a result of type `int`, which is either the number of items successfully scanned, or the value `EOF` if there was an error. You should *always* check the result, since `scanf()` can fail due to circumstances beyond your program's control.

`scanf("%ld", ...)` will, after skipping leading whitespace (including newlines), read text with the syntax of an optionally signed integer constant. Anything following that is left in the input stream.

Without seeing more of your code and the input you're giving it, it's difficult to tell what the problem is.

Using `scanf` can be tricky.  A better approach is to use `fgets()` to read an entire line of input, then `sscanf()` to interpret its contents. By using `fgets()`, you won't be leaving partial input lines waiting for the next call (unless the line is longer than your input buffer), and if the `sscanf()` call fails, it doesn't affect the state of the input stream.

Note, use `fgets()`, *not* `gets()`; `gets()` is inherently unsafe, should never be used, and has been removed from the language standard.